Next.js React app does not load updated page on Link click
I'm using Next.js version 14, the App router, and Next.js's  Link component from next/link. File structure: Folder app/a contains:

page.tsx which fetches the API, and passes the data to the <Table/> component from...
Table.tsx, a client component with "use client". The entire table component is client side because I'm using Mantine's tables

At localhost:3000/a, I have a table populated with data from an API. A column from that table has Links with their hrefs set to localhost:3000/a?param=x. Clicking the link should lead to the same table, but with that column filtered. When I click the link, I can see the URL in my browser address bar update correctly, but the page does not seem to update. However, refreshing the page (now with the new URL) loads the updated and expected table. Also, Right click -> Open in new tab does load the correct data in the new tab.
When I look at my VSCode console, I can see that the API is being fetched with the param when the links are clicked. I noticed that when a link is clicked, GET /a?param=x is not printed to the console, but when the I refresh the page (which has the link's URL), GET /a?param=x does print and the correct data is displayed.
This issue is only for links on /a, going to /a?param=x, not for going from /a to /b.

I did some digging and found that passing a key from my server component (Page) to client component (Table) -- where key={query_param} -- fixed this. I believe the concepts are called "partial rendering" and "soft navigation" for Next? https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#4-partial-rendering
Not Next.js specific: Component does not remount when route parameters change
